# why django querysey index operator return a copy of the object

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I know that django querysey is a generator and not a list.

```
my_items = Item.objects.filter(id = 1)
my_items[0].name = 'joe'
my_items[0].save()
```

In the example my_items[0] is a copy of the object so the save will not modify the object.
while this will work (will not create a copy)

```
my_items = Item.objects.filter(id = 1)
my_item = my_items[0]
my_item.name = 'joe'
my_item.save()
```

Where in django docs (or any where else) it explain this behavior ?
And why did they choose to return a copy of the object and not the object itself ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is documented in [the section about querysets and caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#when-querysets-are-not-cached). It's not just a copy of an existing object. Every time you do this Django makes a separate query to the database, and a new object is created based on the response. Here's an example provided by the documentation:

```
>>> queryset = Entry.objects.all()
>>> print queryset[5] # Queries the database
>>> print queryset[5] # Queries the database again
```

However if your queryset is already evaluated, getting an object using index operator will not hit the database, and you will get the same object every time (as shown in the documentation).

**Update:** I was asked to clearify further, so here it goes:

You think you are getting a *copy* of the object, but that's not strictly true. You are getting two different Python objects, created independently, but based on the same database entry. That's because every time you use the index operator the database is queried and a new object is created (provided the query wasn't evaluated before).

In your case you use the operator two times, both times hitting the database. The first time is in the second line: `my_items[0].name = 'joe'`; and the second time in the third line: `my_items[0].save()`. Every time you do `my_items[0]` you are using the operator, querying the database and creating a new object. As a result you are saving a different object than you modified.

Comment: but what your describe is not my problem - the queryset is not already evaluated.my problem is getting a copy of the object and the object itself.

Comment: I don't understand how it is not your problem. You are not getting the same object exactly *because* the queryset wasn't evaluated before, so every time you use the index operator the database is queried and a new object is created. You *think* you are getting a *copy* of the object, but it is not strictly true. You are getting two different Python objects, created independently, but based on the same database entry.

Comment: i am using the index operator only once, like you said the query set was not evaluated before. my problem is why after it get evaluated i get a copy and not the original. look at the code i added to the question.if like you say i only think i get a copy of the object then why is the save method does not save it to the object ?

Comment: That's not true. You are using the operator two times, both times hitting the database. The first time is in the second line: `my_items[0].name = 'joe'`; and the second time in the third line: `my_items[0].save()`. Every time you do `my_items[0]` you are using the operator, querying the database and creating a new object. As a result you are saving a different object than you modified.

Comment: oh ! i see :). you are right ! can you put it in your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Does the fact that you wrote "my_itMes" in the second line important?

```
Item.objects.filter(pk = 1).update(name = 'Joe')
```

OR

```
myitem = Item.objects.get(id=1)
myitem.name = 'joe'
myitem.save()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#updating-attributes-based-on-existing-fields

And the documentation you asked for:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#filtered-querysets-are-unique

Each time you refine a QuerySet, you get a brand-new QuerySet that is in no way bound to the previous QuerySet. Each refinement creates a separate and distinct QuerySet that can be stored, used and reused.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but i know how to make it work. that was not my question.

Comment: I added the documentation for your question.

Comment: but even if i refine many querysets at the end when i get an object and change it and save it - it modify the original object.